# how to use nodejs to monitor oracle table data

Tags: node.js, oracle

I am trying to find an article that shows this or something similar but i cannot. everything is based on front end. What i want to achieve is ability to check for real-time changes to a database table in oracle and for every new record that gets inserted into this table i would like to run a process for that. I have come across https://dzone.com/articles/real-time-data-with-nodejs-socketio-and-oracle-dat but it deals with front end not exactly sure if this is the way to go.

currently i am using cronjob using php to run my jobs but it affects the application is the `TNS listener` is getting spammed with connection requests. i need to minimize my overall application connections.

below is what i have so far. the query only runs once. what i want it to do is run continuously until it finds a record. once it finds a record for it to run another script

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');
var app;
var httpServer;
var io;

initWebServer();

function initWebServer() {
    app = express();
    httpServer = http.Server(app);
    io = socketio(httpServer);

    app.use(logger('combined'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    //Create 2 static file end points, 1 for public and 1 for bower_components
    //app.use('/', serveStatic(__dirname + '/public'));
    //app.use('/vendor', serveStatic(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

    //Create end points for the application
    //app.get('/api/super-cities', function(req, res, next) {
        //getFavoriteCities(req, res, next, 'API');
    //});

    //app.post('/api/vote', postVote);

    //Create an end point for the database
    //app.get('/db', function(req, res, next) {
        //getFavoriteCities(req, res, next, 'SOCKET_IO');
    //});

    httpServer.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log('Webserver listening on localhost:3000');
        getNewCommsMatrix();
        io.on('change', function() {
            getNewCommsMatrix();
        });
    });
}

function getNewCommsMatrix(){
    oracledb.getConnection(
        dbConfig,
        function(err, connection) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            connection.execute(
                'select * ' +
                  'from ( ' +
                  'SELECT wj.*, min(ts_created) over () as min_created ' +
                        'FROM CCP.worker_jobs wj WHERE flag IN (\'Q\',\'F\') AND (job = \'processCommsMatrixUpload\') ' +
                        'ORDER BY ts_created ' +
                        ') ' +
                        'where ts_created = min_created',
                {},//no binds
                {
                    maxRows: 1,
                    outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
                },
                function(err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        return connection.release(function() {
                            next(err);
                        });
                    }

                    console.log(results.metaData); 
                    console.log(results.rows);   


                    connection.release(function(err) {
                        if (err) return next(err);

                        /*
                        if (context === 'API') {
                            res.send(results.rows);
                        } else if (context === 'SOCKET_IO') {
                            io.emit('change', results.rows);
                            res.send();
                        }
                        */
                    });
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

my cron runs a bash script every minute which runs a process with randomn inter of 2-5s and spawns a maximum of 10.

**cron**

```
CMD=$(ps aux | grep "cli-worker-processQueueCommsMatrixUpload.sh -e $ENV_NAME >>" | grep -v grep | wc -l)

if [[ "$CMD" -lt 10 ]]; then
    COUNTER=1

    if [[ $ENV_NAME == test ]]; then
        while true ; do
            if [[ "$COUNTER" -eq 180 ]]; then
                exit 0
            fi 
            /opt/SP/php7/bin/php /var/httpd/ccp-test/ccp-test.domain.com/scripts/cli-worker-manager.php processQueueCommsMatrixUpload >> /var/httpd/ccp-test/ccp-test.domain.com/scripts/logs/cli-worker-processQueueCommsMatrixUpload.log 2>&1 & 
            sleep 3; 
            COUNTER=$[$COUNTER +1]
        done
    fi

fi
```

**cli-worker-manager.php**

```
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
        $arg = $argv[1];
        $workerManager = new WorkerManager($arg);
        $workerManager->{$arg}();
    }
```

**runs below function**

```
public function processQueueCommsMatrixUpload() {
        $workerJobs = new WorkerJobs;
        $dbh_ro = new DatabaseConnection;

        $queue = $workerJobs->getOldestJob('processCommsMatrixUpload');
        if(count($queue) > 0) {
            $job = $queue[0];
            $filecache = CCPSHARED . "/locks/".$job['id'];


            $condition = [
                'ID' => $job['id'],
                'FLAG' => ['IN', [ 'Q', 'F' ]]
            ];

            if(($job['flag'] == 'F') && ($job['attempts'] = 3)) {
                $this->log->info('job #' . $job['id'] . ' Failed attempts 3 reached ');

                $update = [
                    'SERVER' => gethostname(),
                    'FLAG' => 'T', // T = terminated
                    'ATTEMPTS' => 3,
                    'TS_UPDATED' => 'systimestamp',
                ];

                $result = $workerJobs->updateTable($update, $condition);
                \unlink($filecache);
                return true;
            }

            //recheck to see other worker has not processed this file
            $nextjob = $workerJobs->recheckNextJob((int) $job['id'],'processCommsMatrixUpload');
            if(count($nextjob) > 0){
                //check filecache or create file cache with

                if(\file_exists($filecache)){
                    $this->log->warn('file cache exists, processCommsMatrixUpload has been picked up by other server #' . $job['id'] );
                    return true;
                }
                \touch($filecache);

                $attempts = (empty($nextjob[0]['attempts'])) ? 1 : $nextjob[0]['attempts'];
                $update = [
                    'SERVER' => gethostname(),
                    'FLAG' => 'P',
                    'ATTEMPTS' => $attempts,
                    'TS_UPDATED' => 'systimestamp',
                ];

                $result = $workerJobs->updateTable($update, $condition);

                if(is_string($result)) {
                    $this->log->error('worker job #' . $job['id'] . ' update failure.');

                    $notification = new Notification();
                    $body = 'worker job #' . $job['id'] . ' update failure.';
                    $notification->cliJobs($notification->getSystemEmail(), ['user@domain.com',], $body);
                } else {
                    sleep(rand(2 , 10)); //add random delay between each job from 1-3 secs

                    $ts_start = strtoupper(date('d-M-y h.i.s') ) . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8);
                    $this->log->info('starting job #' . $job['id'] . ' at ' . $ts_start);

                    $this->{$job['job']}($job);
                    if(file_exists($filecache)){
                        \unlink($filecache);
                    }
                    $ts_end = strtoupper(date('d-M-y h.i.s')) . substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8);
                    $this->log->info('finishing job #' . $job['id'] . ' at ' . $ts_end);
                    $this->log->info('job #' . $job['id'] . ' processing time : '. (strtotime($ts_end) - strtotime($ts_start)) .  ' seconds');

                }
            }else{
                $this->log->warn('Job (processCommsMatrixUpload) has been picked up by other server #' . $job['id'] );
                //$notification = new Notification();
                //$body = 'Job (processCommsMatrixUpload) has been picked up by other server #' . $job['id'];
                //$notification->cliJobs($notification->getSystemEmail(), ['user@domain.com'], $body);
            }

        }
        $workerJobs->ccpRO->disconnect();
        return true;
    }
```

i cant run as db trigger because i need it to process the query resultset in php unless there's a way to call php script from db?

the problem is not with db connections, its with `TNS listener` which throws the error as it treats it like a `DDOS` attack.

I thought i can have a single connection open instead of opening new connection every second.

Comment: you could use triggers on the table. it'll be more efficient using Oracle's engine

Comment: Can you provide more detail? You said you're using a cron job to run PHP, but the code you're showing is Node.js... Also, how often does the cron job run (defined "spammed").

Comment: If the app opens a connection then there won't be a difference in connection load between PHP & Node unless you leave the program running all the time, keeping a DB connection open all the time (using oci_pconnect in PHP and using a minimal connection pool in Node.js).  The app would need to respond to an external request to trigger the query execution.  The alternative is to use the Continuous Query Notification features and UTL_HTTP to call out to your app - which would need to be running all the time to listen for these web requests.

Comment: @DanMcGhan I have updated the question

Comment: @ChristopherJones I have tried pooled connection but it crashes my server. my db connection limit is 1000. whta is `Continuous Query Notification` and how does that get used?

Comment: Looks like you're showing some emails in the new code - you should probably remove those. I discuss Continuous Query Notification here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPz3VY_0bXE&t=27m15s and after that how you can communicate with the mid-tier (you'd have to be listening there). Although most of what I've written on this topic does involve the client, you can simply ignore the client side of things. What matters most to you is the communication between the DB and the mid-tier.

Comment: Regarding pooling, sounds like you are doing it 'wrong'.  You say you are spawning 10 - do they complete before the next lot spawn?

Comment: If you want to stick with PHP, there is a PHP Continuous Query Notification example in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/oracle-zendcon-php-2009-129471.pdf

Comment: what if i don't have memcache or similair set up?